# Addresses of elements of type char* in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If we create a `char` array:

```
char strings[3][10] = {"Apple","Banana","Grape"};
```

and a pointer of type char:

```
char *pstrings[] = {"Apple","Banana","Grape"};
```

If we print the addresses of the elements, the char array elements will be 10 bytes apart and the elements of the pointer don't seem to follow one another.

How does your program know where to find the next element of the char pointer if the elements do not follow each other in memory?

Comment: "If we print the addresses of the elements..." Address of what specific elements do you print? Show the printing code.

Answer (score 6):

Well you are initializing the array of `char*` with that information.

In fact `char*[]` contains individual `char*` pointing to the respective string literal. How does it come? Well `"abc"` is basically a null terminated char array that decays into pointer to first element of the array which is `'a'` and now if that is known it isn't hard to access them. The addresses are being stored basically. In the second case you are initializing the `char*` array wit those value. Those string literals need not be from contiguous memory.

```
          +-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+
ADDRESS   |Random   |      |Random     |      |Random   |
          +-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+
          |A|p|p|l|e|      |B|a|n|a|n|a|      |G|r|a|p|e|
          +-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+-+      +-+-+-+-+-+
                     \           |           /
                      \          |          /
                       \         |         /
                        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                        |  0  |  1  |  2  |
                        +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

That's why you got different values when you printed `strings[0]`, `strings[1]` etc.

Program just uses the initialized values that is stored in `pstrings` and that contains the address of those string literals. That's how we use it.

In the first case, same content as your string literals - we are initializing them in the `char` array which are in turn contiguous.

```
          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +
ADDRESS   |strings + 0        |strings + 10       |strings + 20       |
          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +
          |A|p|p|l|e| | | | | |B|a|n|a|n|a| | | | |G|r|a|p|e| | | | | |
          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +
          |         0         |         1         |         2         |
          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +
```

As a result we can have those modifiable strings each being stored in an array of `10` `char`s. `char p[]="abc";` is equivalent to `char p[]={'a','b','c','\0'}` same happens here.

Also know one thing, the second case also the pointer values are stored in contiguous memory.

1. These wonderful ascii-art explanation is provided by [**Keine Lust**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606345/keine-lust).

Comment: @KeineLust.: Can't thank you enough ... and really thanks a lot. I will edit a bit to mention your  wonderful contribution.

Comment: I couldn't resist adding some ASCII art to the explanation :)

Comment: So, just to be clear, pstrings is being initialized with the address of those string literals, thats why they dont appear to be contiguous in memory? but those string literals are contiguous in memory?

Comment: @cesmuh.: The string literals may not be contiguous in memory but when you intiilaize with them the char array then you get  contiguous array of 1d char arrays. Thats it.

Comment: @coderredoc got it. Is this also the case when memory is allocated to a char** to store strings read at runtime?

Comment: @cesmuh.: malloc allocates contiguous memory. So now if you use `strcpy` to copy those literals you will have char arrays which residely contiguously in memory.

Comment: @coderredoc Last question. I ran some code to print addresses elements of a char** after using malloc and strcpy. I saw that the memory did appear to be contiguous, but each element had a size of 32 bytes? First element: Hello     ==>     0000000002790298
Second element: Hello    ==>     00000000027902b8

Comment: @cesmuh.: No offense but now I really don't understand what you asked in  last comment. If it's not too hard ask a new question or do something which can be easily udnerstandable. I will be glad to help you. And thanks for the comment.